# ProtectedRoute is not a Route component. React-Router 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

it seems everything in my code is correct i don't know why this specific problem is being produced and for what reason at the end my protected route will either end up as Route element or redirection to "/"

> Uncaught Error: [ProtectedRoute] is not a  component. All component children of < Routes > must be a < Route > or <React.Fragment>

```
const App = () => {

const [authenticated] = useState(true);

return (

    <div className={AppStyles}>
        <Router>
            <div className="Container">
                <Nav />
                <Routes>
                    <Route
                        path="/*"
                        element={<Bosses />} />
                    <ProtectedRoute
                        path="/admin"
                        element={<Admin />}
                        authenticated={authenticated}
                        redirectTo="/"
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="*"
                        element={<Navigate to="/" />}
                    />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </div>

)
```

}

Protected Route

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Route } from 'react-router-dom'


const ProtectedRoute = ({ element, authenticated, redirectTo, ...rest }) => {
   if (!authenticated) { return <Navigate to={redirectTo} /> }
   return <Route {...rest} element={element} />;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Webpack configuration

```
const path = require("path")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

let mode = "development";
let target = "web";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
     mode = "production";
     target = "browserslist"; // it seems workaround and it's going to be fixed in the nearest future
}
// this is our module.exports
module.exports = {
     mode: mode,
     target: target,
     // this is our output functionality 
     output: {
          // path.resolve(__dirname) will give the absolute path
          // while dirname will give what's "in-place" for the current folder
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
          assetModuleFilename: "images/[hash][ext][query]",
          publicPath: '/'
     },
     module: {
          rules: [
               {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                    type: "asset/resource", //you can use asset/inline but only when you wanna add small portions of icons in your navbar
                    //inlining your assets into js build would make our bundle's size quite big 
               },
               {
                    test: /\.(s[ac]|c)ss$/i,
                    // order matters
                    use: [{
                         loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                         options: { publicPath: "" }
                    },
                         "css-loader",
                         "postcss-loader",
                         "sass-loader"
                    ]
               },
               {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                         loader: "babel-loader"
                    },
               },
          ],
     },
     plugins: [
          new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
          new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
          new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
               template: "./src/index.html"
          })],
     // we still wanna support and js and jsx
     resolve: {
          extensions: [".js", ".jsx",]
     },
     devtool: "source-map",
     devServer: {
          hot: true,
          static: "./dist",
          historyApiFallback: true,
     }
}
```

Comment: `ProtectedRoute` *may* render a `Route` component, it itself isn't a `Route` component and this is the issue.

Comment: Oh i see thank you for answering i might over analyzed things but yeah it seems that's the main problem